# Hide outputs that are not warnings or messages

Tags: r

I have the following basic code:

```
library(dplyr)
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))
```

This code creates an SQLite db and selects a non-existing table. This returns a message: "Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: flights".

For some reason, I cannot suppress this output. I've tried:

```
# suppressMessages
suppressMessages(tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights")))

# suppressWarnings
suppressWarnings(tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights")))

# use invisible
invisible(tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights")))

# use sink
sink(tempfile())
tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))
sink()

# via tryCatch
tryCatch({
    tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))
})
```

Is there any other way to remove output that will work in this case?

Comment: Maybe `tryCatch`? I think you can also change how R responds to errors globally using `options()`.

Comment: I already tried tryCatch and I was actually running my code inside a tryCatch environment. I've added this to the original question.

Comment: That's not how you use `tryCatch`. If you read `?tryCatch` you will probably learn that you'd need to do something like `tryCatch(...,error = function(e) invisible(NULL))`.

Comment: `purrr::safely(tbl)(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))`

Comment: `tryCatch(tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights")), error = function (e) NULL)`

Comment: I forgot the error handler. This solved my problem.